# Which anime episodes of Cardcaptors correspond to which manga chapters?

Tags: cardcaptor-sakura

I enjoy watching anime episodes based on which manga chapters I read. I couldn't find any source on exactly which *Cardcaptors* episodes are based on which chapters? I am only asking about the original series and not the currently airing Clear Card Arc

Could someone tell me like they did with the *Aria* Manga?

Comment: does this include the currently airing Clear Card Arc?

Comment: Yes. it includes that.

Comment: Well is anyone researching so they can make me the list because I answered the question and you just left.

Comment: i was clarifying if you wanted just the old series or wanted the new Clear Card Arc Series for anyone else who might want to answer. since you have said it does you'll have to wait because, as i said, the Clear Card Arc is currently airing as such it's not possible to answer in regards to the Clear Card Arc if the episodes haven't even been released in japan. it's a 22 episode series and as of posting this comment we only have 4 episodes in japan (according to anichart)

Comment: Oh since you can't answer until that series is over could you just do a list for the original series now?

Comment: i have edited your question to indicate you're only asking about the original series and not the Clear Card Arc like you have indicated in your recent comment. that being said i don't have an answer. all i know is that there are some changes between the anime and manga but no chapter to episode breakdown

Comment: Do you know anyone who can give me one like with the Aria manga?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%97%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%81%95%E3%81%8F%E3%82%89#%E3%82%B5%E3%83%96%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) (the unlisted episode is anime original),

> **"Clow Card" arc**
>
> Season 1:
>
> - Episode 1: Vol. 1, ch. 1
> - Episode 3: Vol. 1, ch. 3
> - Episode 6: Vol. 1, ch. 4-5
> - Episode 8: Vol. 2, ch. 8
> - Episode 9: Vol. 2, ch. 9
> - Episode 10: Vol. 2, ch. 6-7
> - Episode 16: Vol. 5, ch. 19
> - Episode 17: Vol. 4, ch. 16-17
> - Episode 18: Vol. 4, ch. 18
> - Episode 25: Vol. 3, ch. 11-12 & Vol.2, ch. 8
> - Episode 26: Vol. 3, ch. 14 & Vol. 4, ch. 15
> - Episode 35: Vol. 6, ch. 23
>
> Season 2:
>
> - Episode 39: Vol. 8, ch. 33
> - Episode 41: Vol. 5, ch. 20
> - Episode 42: Vol. 5, ch. 20-21
> - Episode 44: Vol. 5, ch. 21
> - Episode 45: Vol. 6, ch. 23-25
> - Episode 46: Vol. 6, ch. 25-26
>
> **"Sakura Card" arc**
>
> Season 3:
>
> - Episode 47: Vol. 7, ch. 27
> - Episode 48: Vol. 7, ch. 28
> - Episode 49: Vol. 7, ch. 29
> - Episode 50: Vol. 7, ch. 29-30
> - Episode 51: Vol. 8, ch. 31-32
> - Episode 52: Vol. 9, ch. 36
> - Episode 54: Vol. 8, ch. 34 & Vol. 9, ch. 35
> - Episode 59: Vol. 9, ch. 37-38
> - Episode 65: Vol. 9, ch. 38 & Vol. 10, ch. 39
> - Episode 66: Vol. 10, ch. 39-40
> - Episode 67: Vol. 10, ch. 41-42
> - Episode 68: Vol. 10, ch. 40
> - Episode 69: Vol. 11, ch. 43-44
> - Episode 70: Vol. 11, ch. 45 & Vol. 12, ch. 46